# How to stop the function from returning until all the Futures in the function are executed in scala?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, parallel-processing, future

I am trying to process some files asynchronously, with the ability to choose the number of threads the program should use. But I want to wait till `processFiles()` is completed processing all the files. So, I am searching for ways to stop function from returning until all the Futures are done executing. And it would be very helpful if anyone gives any ideas to approach this problem. Here is my sample code.

```
object FileReader{

    def processFiles(files: Array[File]) = {
        val execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
        implicit val execContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(execService)

        val processed = files.map { f =>
            Future {
                val name = f.getAbsolutePath()
                val fp = Source.fromFile(name)
                var data = ""
                fp.getLines().foreach(x => {
                    data = data ++ s"$x\n"
                })
                fp.close()
                // process the data.
                println("Processing ....")
                data
            }
        }
        execContext.shutdown()

    }

        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Start")


        val tmp = new File("/path/to/files")
        val files = tmp.listFiles()
        val result = processFiles(files)
        println("done processing")
        println("done work")

    }

}
```

I am thinking if my usage of Future here is wrong, please correct me if I am wrong.

My expected output :

```
Start
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
done processing
done work
```

My current output:

```
Start
done processing
done work
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
Processing ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Future.traverse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse%5BA,B,M%5BX%5D%3C:IterableOnce%5BX%5D%5D(in:M%5BA%5D)(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future%5BB%5D)(implicitbf:scala.collection.BuildFrom%5BM%5BA%5D,B,M%5BB%5D%5D,implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BM%5BB%5D%5D) to combine all the `Future`'s for individual file processing and `Await.result` on them after:

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.io.Source
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object FileReader {

  def processFiles(files: Array[File]) = {
    val execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
    implicit val execContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(execService)

    //Turn `Array[Future[String]]` to `Future[Array[String]]`
    val processed = Future.traverse(files.toList) { f =>
      Future {
        val name = f.getAbsolutePath()
        val fp = Source.fromFile(name)
        var data = ""
        fp.getLines()
          .foreach(x => {
            data = data ++ s"$x\n"
          })
        fp.close()
        // process the data.
        println("Processing ....")
        data
      }
    }
    //TODO: Put proper timeout here
    //Execution will be blocked until all futures completed
    Await.result(processed, 30 minute)
    execContext.shutdown()

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Start")

    val tmp = new File(
      "/path/to/file"
    )
    val files = tmp.listFiles()
    val result = processFiles(files)
    println("done processing")
    println("done work")

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan , for your response, even though this looks correct. I am getting the following error :

`inferred type arguments [String,Nothing,Array] do not conform to method traverse's type parameter bounds [A,B,M[X] <: IterableOnce[X]]
  val processed = Future.traverse(files) { f =>
`
Any idea what might be the reason? I am trying to change the type of `files`

Comment: @Manikishan thanks for a comment, I've edited answer. My bad, I'm sorry. Short answer: files needs to be converted to list.

Comment: Changing files type to `Seq[File]` worked.

Comment: @Manikishan `listFiles` as far as I remember. Anyway, traverse accepts `scala.collection.IterableOnce` and `Array` does not have such inheritance.

Comment: @Manikishan upvote also appreciated. Thank you for question!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ivan Kurchenko. The solution worked. I am posting my final version of the code that worked.

```
object FileReader {

    def processFiles(files: Seq[File]) = {
        val execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
        implicit val execContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(execService)
        //Turn `Array[Future[String]]` to `Future[Array[String]]`
        val processed = Future.traverse(files) {
            f =>
                Future {
                    val name = f.getAbsolutePath()
                    val fp = Source.fromFile(name)
                    var data = ""
                    fp.getLines()
                        .foreach(x => {
                            data = augmentString(data) ++ s"$x\n"
                        })
                    fp.close()
                    // process the data.
                    println("Processing ....")
                    f
                }
        }
//      TODO: Put proper timeout here
//      Execution will be blocked until all futures completed
        Await.result(processed, 30.minute)
        execContext.shutdown()

    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Start")

        val tmp = new File(
            "/path/to/file"
        )
        val files =tmp.listFiles.toSeq
        val result = processFiles(files)


        println("done processing")
        println("done work")

    }
}
```